# Компиляция программы непосредственно для уровня микроархитектуры

Tags: ассемблер, архитектура, компиляция, процессор, микроархитектура

Изучаю архитектуру компьютера, есть вопрос. Но для начала что я понял:

Берется архитектура набора команд (набор инструкции то бишь *язык ассемблера* для конкретного процессора?) то бишь MOV, XOR и [т.д](http://www.avprog.narod.ru/progs/emu8086/8086_instruction_set.html), затем эти инструкции выполняются уровнем микроархитектуры, трактом данных (регистры + арифметико-логичское устройство, этим занимается микропрограмма либо сам микропроцессор)

Спрашивается может ли компилятор создать код для выполнения непосредственно для микроархитектуры, минуя архитектуру набора команд? Если я всё правильно понимаю, то нет, ибо микроархитектура это уже набор регистров (группа ячеек памяти из 8, 16 или 32 бит) в каждой из которой записана определённая инструкция в виде нулей и единиц. Соответственно, например компилятор языка Си не сможет выдать код (101111101011) который сможет выполнить конкретный процессор. Ибо сначала нужно будет перевести на [архитектуру набора команд процессора например 8086](http://www.avprog.narod.ru/progs/emu8086/8086_instruction_set.html).
А затем микроархитектура уже сама интерпретирует код понятный ему, тобишь MOV, XOR и т.д

Я верно всё понимаю?

Comment: @Child,

    Я верно всё понимаю братюни?

в общем случае - **нет**, а применительно к современному состоянию x-86 мыслите в правильном русле.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос интересный. И я думаю, заключается, в основном, в том, существует и открыт ли (доступен, когда процессор вставлен в обычную серийную материнскую плату) в современных процессорах интерфейс для непосредственной загрузки последовательностей микрокоманд для исполнения. Кто их знает. Скорее нет - зачем intel или AMD открывать для сторонних пользователей низкоуровневый интерфейс? Только лишние дыры в безопасности. По скорости вряд ли удастся что-то существенное выиграть. Кроме того, программирование в микрокомандах с большой вероятностью упрётся в пропускную способность памяти. Т.к. исполнительных устройств много и на каждый такт надо почти каждому из них сообщить новую команду.

Вот вероятность, что на обычном компьютере можно перепрошить микрокод, т.е. программу в процессоре, которая описывает, на какие микрокоманды разбивается каждая обычная команда, немного повыше. Но я бы тоже поставил на то, что нельзя.

Почитайте [ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Микрокод](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4), а ещё лучше - английский вариант.

**Upd:** хотя нет, для второго есть средства: "*Intel опубликовала способ, которым ОС или BIOS могут обновить микрокод (это надо делать после каждого reset'a - изменения не сохраняются), но содержимое микрокода не документировано. Более того, оно закодировано и обвешано check summ'aми.*" [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual](http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/manual/253668.pdf)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366837/what-is-intel-microcode

Answer (score 1):

У процессоров делают разные режимы работы, в которых используются разные инструкции. Один из режимов основной, в который другие инструкции декодируются. Декодеры реализованы железно, из транзисторов.

У процессоров для ПК наличие режимов x86 и amd64 связано с совместимостью со старыми программами. Расположение декодера вопрос, возможно он стоит перед кеш памятью программ.

Многорежимность работы процессора встречается довольно часто.

Процессор ARM7 имеет основной режим работы ARM32 и 16 разрядный режим Thumb, команды которого в два раза короче и их значительно меньше. Это уменьшает размер кода и в простых задачах не сказывается на быстродействие.

Answer (score 0):

> Я верно всё понимаю братюни?

Извините, но такое общение может раздражать. Рекомендую избавиться

По сути Вашего вопроса. Мое видение такое:

1. Смотрим на решаемую нами задачу и формируем список инструкций, которые нам нужны. Они могут быть такие же как в любой другой архитектуре, а могут и совсем другими. Все зависит от целей задачи которую решает дизайнер микроархитектуры
2. Про компилятор думают только тогда, когда сам дизайн уже сформирован
3. Изучается список языков программирования, которые могут позволить вам Ваш дизайн микроархитектуры и набора инструкций, которые Вы спроектировали выразить на этом языке. К примеру существуют Verilog, VHDL.

И самый главный вопрос перед тем как взяться за такую задачу: Это действительно нужно решать или это просто фан?

Рекомендую почитать Таненбаума, отличный пацан и хорошо поясняет многие вещи!